# WPF. Не привязывается модель

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Суть в том, что не могу привязать в `xaml` модель, созданную во `viewmodel`.
Если модель получается из `SelectedItem ListBox`'а, то все норм. А если через `new` то ничего. Сам код.

```
viewmodel
        private CCard selectedCard;
        public CCard SelectedCard
        {
            get { return selectedCard; }
            set
            {
                selectedCard = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCard");
            }
        }
        private Commands selectedRegnumCommand;
        public Commands SelectedRegnumCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedRegnumCommand ??
                    (selectedRegnumCommand = new Commands(obj =>
                    {
                        selectedCard = getSelectedCard(SelectedRegnum.Regnum);                        
                    }));
            }
        }
```

`getSelectedCard` - возвращает объект типа CCard

```
xaml
<StackPanel x:Name="SP_cardInfo" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="300" DataContext="{Binding SelectedCard}">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="120*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="180*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Номер документа:" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Tbl_regNum" Text="{Binding SelectedCard.Regnum, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,64,0" />
</Grid>
</StackPanel>

CCard
        public string Regnum
        {
            get { return _regnum; }
            set
            {
                _regnum = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Regnum");
            }
        }
```

В модели реализовал `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Другие моменты работают. Я так понимаю, что проблема именно в том, что `SelectedCard` создается через `new`. Подскажите где туплю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каюсь, проморгал момент. Обращаюсь напрямую к полю `selectedCard`, а не через метод `public CCard SelectedCard`. Поэтому поле меняется, но интерфейс об этом не знает, отсюда и не идет биндинг в `xaml`. А также вылез за пределы контекста

Comment: Т.е. ложечки-то нашлись, да? :)

Comment: Ага, и осадочек от невнимательности тоже)

Answer (score 1):

Вы задаете `DataContext` у `StackPanel`

```
DataContext="{Binding SelectedCard}"
```

А потом работаете вне этого контекста

```
{Binding SelectedCard.Regnum, ...}
```

Comment: Это я уже по разному пробовал. Все равно не работает. Изначально было `Text="{Binding Path=Regnum, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`